# Same user asking same question under different user name

Tags: discussion

I have a feeling that it is the same person asking the same question under different user names - [What is the reason for absence of cyclone in south atlantic and south eastern pacific](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/what-is-the-reason-for-absence-of-cyclone-in-south-atlantic-and-south-eastern-pa) and then here again - [what is the role of absence of land in south atlantic ocean cyclone formation](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/what-is-the-role-of-absence-of-land-in-south-atlantic-ocean-cyclone-formation) and the first one - [In the South Atlantic and South-Eastern Pacific regions in tropical latitudes, cyclone does not originate. What is the reason?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/in-the-south-atlantic-and-south-eastern-pacific-regions-in-tropical-latitudes-c). A simple ip address test can prove this. Is SE capable of this and blocking him ?

Answer (score 4):

In general, if you see issues like this, flag one of the person's posts for a moderator's attention.

The moderators, and - if needed - Stack Exchange staff, have a panoply of tools to help identify sock-puppets and other multiple accounts.

And do bear in mind that just having multiple accounts is in and of itself not a problem, and is not against the rules.

**However**, if any combination of those accounts does anything that a single account would be unable to do, then that **is** against the rules. Some examples of this are: voting on each other's posts, getting rep from accepting each other's answers, multiple votes of the same kind on the same question. Whereas asking the same question repeatedly is something that a single account can do, and is, AIUI, not against the rules.

Comment: IIRC that is the third time that question was asked in the past 2 weeks under 3 different names. Each time the question was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Asking the same question repeatedly is something that a single account can do, and is, AIUI, not against the rules.

Comment: a single account fine. How about a single user posing as 3 ?

Comment: @gansub a user having multiple accounts is ok as long as they don't use them in ways that a single account cannot do.  For example, if you have two accounts you cannot use them to vote for each other, as you cannot upvote your own posts making that an abuse of the system.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with having multiple accounts as long as you don't use them to circumvent the rules.

Examples:

- A single user can post many questions, so a single person can use multiple accounts to ask many questions.
- A single user can only vote once up/down on a post, so a user with multiple accounts can only use one of their accounts to vote on a specific post.
- A single user can cast 1 close / reopen / delete vote on a pst, so a user with multiple accounts can only use one of their accounts to cast these votes on a specific post.
- A single user cannot vote on their own posts, so a user with multiple accounts may not use their accounts to vote for each other.
- A single user has a maximum daily allotment of votes and flags, so a user with multiple accounts may not exceed these limits in total across the accounts.

As you can see, the issues with multiple accounts are primarily abuse of voting to wield more close vote and deletion influence and to pump reputation with multiple votes into themselves or others.  Those kind of activities are actionable and will be dealt with when they become apparent.